# Batch file to separate one single log file to many logs based on different session id's

Tags: batch-file, logging

For example, these are 3 lines of my log:

> DEBUG - 2014-01-06 02:18:07,346 TraceWriter.Butler:
> zhnpz7pBrH0R6lXzlFxbdSD:/Butler :
>
> INFO - 2014-01-06 02:18:07,361  TraceWriter.Butler:
> zhnpz7pBrH0R6lXzlFxbdSD:/Butler :
>
> INFO - 2014-01-06 08:27:10,533  TraceWriter.Butler:
> Aa3efY237sf96AGEDn1AJ9-:/Butler :

Here I have 2 different session ids "zhnpz7pBrH0R6lXzlFxbdSD" & "Aa3efY237sf96AGEDn1AJ9-"
So I want 2 different text file, each files containing only the lines of one particular session ID.

This could be helpful: Always the session ids are of length 23 characters and always starts at 53rd string/literal position. (just an example number)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q21549658.txt) DO (
 SET destfile=%%a
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 >>"!destfile:~52,23!.log" ECHO(%%a
 endlocal
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q21549658.txt` for my testing. Your data seems to be one character short in the last two lines - these seem to have the nominated strings starting in col 52, not 53 (but might be a cut-and-paste problem, too).

Files produced are "sessionname.log" - like "zhnpz7pBrH0R6lXzlFxbdSD.log" - and will append to any existing file with those names. Assumes that the target filename generated is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with awk:

```
awk '{s=substr($0,53,23);print $0 >> s}' file
```

So it will get the sessionid by taking the characters you specified and save it in "s". Then it will append each line of your input file to a file named the same as the session "s".

Comment: Hi Mark, It is not working. I need 2 different files each for one session id. Is there anything that works like substr in batch scripting ?

Comment: This will create as many files as there are session ids. So if you have 2 session ids in your file, you will get 2 output files.

Comment: Sorry, am not aware on how to run an awk file in windows 8. I saved the code u wrote in .awk file and double clicked it, nothing happens.Do i need to install something to run awk files ?

Comment: I hadn't realised you were on Windows, and sadly Windows is not blessed with all the lovely Unix tools like awk/sed/grep. You could install them from here http://unxutils.sourceforge.net but I think you may be better off going with the Windows solution suggested by @"MC ND"

Comment: Yes agreed..!! Yeah but thanks for ur help mark :) Lemme try binging for more solutions or try some scripting by myself :)

Comment: Are there always exactly two streams mixed up in your log? Or sometime more?

Comment: Windows-y VBscript thing answer added.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in ("c:\somewhere\file.log") do (
    for /f "tokens=4 delims=:" %%b in ("%%~a") do for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%c in ("%%~b") do (
        >>"c:\target\%%~c.log" echo(%%a
    )
)
```

For each line in input file, take the adecuate token (using colon as delimiter) and add the line to the adecuated file.

Comment: Hi MC ND, the above batch script is not working. the cmd prompts just appears n disappears. I checked in the target directory,changed the path and checked, still no files are generated. I placed pause in between the lines of code, it just exits before "for /f..."

Comment: @user3270348, my fault, sorry, copied and pasted from where i shouldn't. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as you are on Windows and sadly lacking awk, here is a VBscript version. Save it in a file called "split.vbs" and then run it like this:

```
cscript /nologo split.vbs < yourlogfile
```

Of course, you can batch that if you like.

```
Const ForAppending = 8
Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
   Line = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   fields=Split(Line,":")
   session=Trim(fields(3))
   set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(session, ForAppending, True)
   objFile.WriteLine(Line)
   objFile.close
Loop
```

It basically reads a line from standard input, i.e. from your log file. It then splits the line into its constituent fields using the colon character as separator. The session is then extracted and trimmed of spaces. A file is then opened for append with the name of the session and the line is written to that file. This repeats till the whole log has been processed.